# Mercurial checkout

Tags: mercurial

Hello I am using Mercurial for version control of all of my projects.
My projects  have a folder structure like this.

```
www.Project.com
    01 – Consultancy(excluded)
    02 – Information Architecture
    03 – Content
    04 – Branding
        Fonts (excluded)
        Guidelines
        Logo
    05 – Design
        Graphics
        Stock Photography
    06 – Code WP-Content
        Plugins
        Themes
    07 – Marketing
        Email
        SEO
        Social Media
```

After finishing the static HTML I like to setup a Wordpress theme. But I don't like to have the whole folder structure in my web directory. Is there a way to push and pull only the plugins and themes folder to Wordpress without the other directory's?

Comment: This questoin is already been asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011498/using-mercurial-hg-how-to-push-just-one-file-or-one-directory-out

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .hgignore functionality - see [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a separate repository for `06 – Code WP-Content`.  That way you can push it separately.  If everything is in one repository you have to push everything.

Comment: But what about sub repository?  I have tried these lines      
`hg clone https://domain.com/www-project-com www-Project-com  
cd www-Project-com  
hg init Code-WP-Content  
echo Code-WP-Content = Code-WP-Content > .hgsub  
hg add .hgsub `  
  
But when I try to clone the Code-WP-Content map I get all the data of the other maps  


`hg clone https://domain.com/www-project-com/Code-WP-Content Code-WP-Content `

sorry about the messy response but I have tried to make it better but didn't succeed

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Mercurial's subrepository "feature of last resort".  You can nest repositories in Mercurial without using the subrepository feature but you will have to manage them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.

I have decided to solve the issue by creating a alias on my websever to the 
*www.Project.com/06 – Code WP-Content* path leaving the rest in tackt